# How to prevent user to edit web api request (Http Requests) by using browser network tab

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

Now we can edit the xhr request using Network tab of browser inspector.
A sample image -[Image showing browser network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27vMI.jpg).

[image]

Here we can change the xhr request parameter and can resend again. Some times this may affect our website security. How to restrict this?.

Comment: you can encode your parameters and you can also use token to make sure user can not send request directly from elsewhere

Comment: you cannot do anything in browser end as suggested you can use token to validate each request.

Comment: @Prashanth,@Khagesh Can u explain little more.How do you recognize where those requests came from?